# MongoDB aggregate with conditional sums

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to do a special mongoDB query.

I have a collection with documents like these:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6"),
    "works" : [ 
        {
            "code" : "A001",
            "name" : "Cambiar bombilla",
            "orderId" : "53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6",
            "price" : 1400,
            "ID" : 1,
            "lazyLoaded" : true,
            "status" : 0,
            "Date" : ISODate("2014-07-21T10:31:55.063Z"),
            "TechnicianId" : "538efd918163b19307c59e8e",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ccec1bf2bf4d5952b2f205")
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "A005",
            "name" : "Cambiar bombilla 5",
            "price" : 1050,
            "type" : "Bombillas",
            "TechnicianId" : "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ccfdbdf2bf4d5952b2f206")
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "A004",
            "name" : "Cambiar bombilla 4",
            "price" : 1010,
            "type" : "Bombillas",
            "TechnicianId" : "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e",
            "date" : "2014-07-21T11:50:52.702Z",
            "orderId" : "53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53ccfe9c109c100000ad688a")
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "A002",
            "name" : "Cambiar bombilla 2",
            "price" : 1030,
            "type" : "Bombillas",
            "TechnicianId" : "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e",
            "date" : "2014-07-21T11:57:37.065Z",
            "orderId" : "53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53cd0036109c100000ad688b")
        }, 
        {
            "code" : "A003",
            "name" : "Cambiar bombilla 3",
            "price" : 1050,
            "type" : "Bombillas",
            "TechnicianId" : "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e",
            "date" : "2014-07-21T11:59:35.586Z",
            "orderId" : "53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6",
            "_id" : ObjectId("53cd00a7109c100000ad688c")
        }
    ],
    "Items" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "534ba71f394835a7e51dd938",
            "total":50
            "qty" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "534664b081362062015d1b77",
            "qty" : 2,
            "total":30
        }
    ]}
```

Now, I want to do a query to get the works with TechnicianId=5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e , the sum of the "price" for these works deducting the sum of items.total, the quantity of the total works for these documents deducting the sum of items.total.

For this example I want something like this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6"),
            "works.totalsumfortech" : 1050+1010+1030+1050 - (50+30),//Sum of works of this technicianId deducting the items.total qty
            "works.total":1400+1050+1010+1030+1050-(50+30)//Summ of all works of document deducting the items.total qty
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This is my current query but I don't get the expected result..

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        { "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {"OrderState": {$in:['Review','Archived']}},
                {'works.TechnicianId':'5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e'}
            ]
        }},
        {$group: {
         _id: "$_id",
         'total': {$subtract:[{$sum: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$works.TechnicianId", "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e" ] } , 2, 1 ]},{$sum: '$Items.total'}]
         'total': {$subtract:[{$sum: '$works.price'},{$sum: '$Items.total'}]
         }
         }]);
```

Comment: You need to use `$unwind` on arrays first. You have asked similar things before.

Comment: Yes i know but my question its in the sum with the conditional, i dont know if i can do it this.

Comment: If you "know" then your statement would show an `$unwind`. It does not. This is why it does not work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Modern

This actually is a lot easier with modern releases of MongoDB. In the particular case there is no actual "aggregation" across documents, though there is a significant reduction in data returned and "aggregation within the document" to be applied.

The modern take on this allows this sort of reshaping and selection from data in arrays without resorting to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in order to process:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    //"OrderState": { "$in":["Review","Archived"]},
    "works.TechnicianId":"5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "works": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "techTotal": {
            "$sum": {
              "$map": {
                "input": { 
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$works",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$this.TechnicianId",
                        "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "in": "$$this.price"
              }    
            }
          },
          "items_total": { "$sum": "$Items.total" },
          "worksTotal": { "$sum": "$works.price" }
        },
        "in": {
          "totalSumForTech": {
            "$subtract": [ "$$techTotal", "$$items_total" ]
          },
          "total": {
            "$subtract": [ "$$worksTotal", "$$items_total" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The changes since originally asked are that [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accepts an "array" as input when used in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or similar stage context in addition to the traditional role as an accumulator. So rather than "unwinding" an array, you can do things like `{ "$sum": "$Items.total" }` which retuns an array of values from the specified property by the inner notation and then "reduces" those values via [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). That's a big improvement on it's own.

Additional improvements are [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/). Where the latter is applied in order to return just the matching entries of an array to a given condition, and for former allows "reshaping" of array contents. Both are common methods in other programming languages for dealing with arrays and have basically the same function here.

This means you can extract the `"price"` values from the `"works"` array matching the technician as is required, and then total those using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) as an "array of values" in the same way as described earlier.

The other addition is [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/), which allows a block to be declared with "variables" for usage within that block. In this case we can compute those "totals" from the arrays and then apply [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to the calculated values in order to come to the final result.

The advantage over earlier versions is you can do this without separating aggregation pipeline stages. And of course the `$$items_total` can be used here in place of repeating the full statement to calculate. Also the general separation of calculations makes the final output block a bit easier to read. So it's really just "using variables" in much the same way you do in regular programming.

The big gain here is this becomes simply [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), and not a whole chain of pipeline stages just to get to the final calculated result from each document.

---

### Original

As stated earlier, you **need** to use [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) when working with arrays in MongoDB aggregation. The aggregation operations do not work on each array element unless you do this.

Other problems here are that within the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage all of the "top level" operations need to be [group aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/). Things that are not like [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) are not allowed, so you need to do those operations either within something like [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) where possible or in another pipeline stage:

```
db.orders.aggregate([

    // Match documents "and" is implied in MongoDB. Not required unless
    // against the same field
    { "$match": {
        "OrderState": { "$in":["Review","Archived"]},
        "works.TechnicianId":"5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e"
    }},

    // Unwind Items first
    { "$unwind": "$Items" },

    // Group to get that total
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "works": { "$first": "$works" },
        "items_total": { "$sum": "$Items.total" }
    }},

    // Unwind works to "de-normalize"
    { "$unwind": "$works" },

    // Group conditionally on "TechnicianId" and the full total
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "techTotal": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$eq": [ 
                        "$works.TechnicianId", 
                        "5383577a994be8b9a9e3f01e"
                    ]},
                    "$works.price",
                    0 
                ]
            }
        },
        "worksTotal": { "$sum": "$works.price" },
        "items_total": { "$first": "$items_total" }
    }},

    // Project to do math and other re-shaping
    { "$project": {
        "works": {
            "totalSumForTech": {
                "$subtract": [ "$techTotal", "$items_total" ]
            },
            "total": {
                "$subtract": [ "$worksTotal", "$items_total" ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

On the sample document (though I need to drop the `$match` since that data does not exist in your sample ) the results are:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c7fd86d624b06abc76e8f6"),
    "works" : {
            "totalSumForTech" : 4060,
            "total" : 5460
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, i thought its more easy..Its very difficult. My principal problem its i dont know use the unwind correcly.

Comment: @colymore Now you have an example you should be able to reflect on other situation where you are trying to work with values in arrays.

Comment: Yes, i will do.Thanks